# How can I append a form and its file input in each table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Jsfiddle application [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fPtMq/27/). If you type in a question in the textarea, and then click on the "Add Question" button, it appends the question and a question number in the table below (you can teest this a couple of times if you wish).

Now below the table is a file input which is stored in another form. My question is that how can I put the form code which contains the file input in the table so that everytime a question is added, it appends the question number and question but it also appends the file input for each row?

Comment: its better to change markup and put the added-questions table to the top.

Comment: i mean, its better to put the file upload under the #question table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way you have been doing it. Just remember to change these lines accordingly to whatever you expect at server side such as file input's name.

```
var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>"); 
var $fileImage = '<p id="f1_upload_form"><br/><label>File: <input name="fileImage" type="file" id="fileImage" /></label></p>';
$image.append($fileImage);
$tr.append($image);
```

Now you just need to move the upload button to the bottom of the table still inside the form wrapping the table.

Here is [a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NujcX/).

Comment: This does append it to a new row, but what I want to know is that when I click the upload button within the row, will it upload the file  to the upload.php through the form tag because that is what I need to do to successfully upload a file. At the moment the file input is appended into a new row but I'm not sure wether the files will upload successfully as it has no form tag to call up on. Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated the answer. Just move the upload button at the bottom of the table inside the `<form>`, every input will be send to the server when user submits this form.

Comment: Just to clarify, if i add 3 questions and I add a file for each input in their rows, if I click 'upload' for the file input in the first row, then what will happen? Will only the first row file input be uploaded?

Comment: yes, only one file will be uploaded, your problem is not related to the js, its related to the markup.

Comment: That is fine, as long as it uploads a file one at a time when an upload is clicked and the only file uloaded is the  one in the file input which the upload button matches to then its ok.

Comment: It will upload everything enclosed by the `<form>`, not one at a time but *everything*. I hope you understand what is sent when you submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of File Input and then add it to the row:

```
var fileinput = $("#fileinput").val();
```

Comment: I really need the file input to be appended to each row so that if the user at any time wants to upload a file for one of the questions, they can use the file input within the row.

Comment: so its better to add the file upload input after question has been added.

Comment: The way Alexander has done it above is correct. But I want to know how can each file input call up with in the form action upload.php to successfully be able to upload a file. The form at the bottom does this but how can I get the file inputs which are apppended to be able to use the form action upload.php to upload files?

Comment: understood, you can make the add question submit for doing this, the question will be added, file will be uploaded, and user can add another question upon success.

Comment: do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: yes, i know, you wrote the codes a little complicated, i should write it from scratch. i can't find the startUpload() function in your js.